# Derivatives in complex space (and complex coefficients).

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

> What's the derivative of $f(z)=z^b$ and $g(z)=a^z$ for any $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$?

So, z as well as a and b are complex and I seriously have no clue how to approach this. My first idea was to define $a=a_1+ia_2$ and $b=b_1+ib_2$ and use the same method as in real space. Meaning, $f'(z)=b_1z^{(b_1-1)+ib_2}$, but that doesn't seem right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $z^b=e^{b\log z}$ in a suitable [branch](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6ooays5fQAhUIxVQKHdEfDyMQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FComplex_logarithm&usg=AFQjCNFaDjsIchyUNqfaCtVcz-5PlUV2MA)

Comment: The function $f(z) = z^b$ is defined as $f(z)=e^{b\log(z)}$.  Inasmuch as $\log(z)$ is a multivalued function, $f(z)$ is multivalued for non-integer values of $b$.

If we cut the plane, then the function $f(z)$ is complex analytic and $f'(z)=bz^{b-1}$ on each Riemann sheet.